# Revert to the original document folder

Tags: document

I have a unique problem and though I have tried to solve it on my own I couldn't...

The problem is as follows:

- Please take a backup of your files before you attempt to solve the problem.
- If you right click on the documents folder or downloads folder on the desktop then a menu opens.
- Out of the many menu options, two options are there, namely **`copy`** and **`move to`**.
- If you click on either of the two options a sub menu appears with other options: **`home`** or **`desktop`**.
- If you select **`home`** then a dialog box appears asking if you want to **`merge the folders`**.
- If you click to **`merge the folders`**, the documents folder changes its appearance. It appears as a document with a lock on the top right corner and cross on the bottom right corner.

Now the document folder is not opening. it also shows that it's not a folder.

How can I revert back to the original document folder?

If you want I could send screen shots of the problem.

Comment: From what you have described it looks like you tried to copy/move the **Document** folder to its original location: **Home**. You cannot merge the original folder with itself.

Comment: @user68186 ur correct but how do i undo it?????

Answer (score 0):

You could try to:

- First, using the menu actions you have already described, move the **`document`** folder to an alternate location.
- For example, you could create a new subfolder on the **`desktop`**, or within another path, or perhaps on another drive.
- Then, once the **`document`** folder has been removed from your desktop, you could move it again, from the alternate location, back to the **`desktop`**.

Also, some other things you could look at, and try:

- View the **`desktop`** folder in a file browser or command-line shell to see if **`document`** shows as a folder or not.
- On the **`desktop`**, try to rename the **`document`** folder to some other name to see if it is restored to be accessed as a folder.

In the end, if this functionallity has been corrupt, you may have to create a new user and move (or copy) all your existing home/desktop files to the new user, and then delete the "corrupt" user.